Странное поле перед текстом
Есть такой код
if(isset($attachment)){
      if($filetype == "png" || $filetype == "gif" || $filetype == "jpeg"){
        echo'<a href="/post/attachments/"'.$attachment.'"><img style="width: 500px; transform: translate(-93px, 46px);" src="/post/attachments/'.$attachment.'"></a><br><br>';
      }
      else if($filetype == "mp4"){
        echo('<video width="500px" style="transform: translate(-93px, 46px);" src="/post/attachments/'.$attachment.'" controls></video>');
      }
    }
    echo'<h1 style="width: 50%; font-size: 42px; transform: translateY(60px);">'.$text.'</h1><br><br><br></div>
    <br><br><br><br>';

если изображение прикладывается, то все хорошо, если изображения нету, то получается это

как исправить? пробовал поменять css

Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Удалите из вашего кода атрибуты  style="transform: translate(-93px, 46px);" и style="width: 50%; font-size: 42px; transform: translateY(60px);" и попробуйте ещё раз. На будущее: старайтесь избегать встроенные стили. На стадии разработки они пишутся, чтобы лишний раз не дёргаться по файлам, а потом провисают в коде и мешают жить.)
